# How to update an item in the state after the previous values of the state get updated?

Tags: reactjs

I was building a react price tracking app which will take all of your expenses,income and then list them.

I had to update the budget after the item has been added either to the expense or an income but because of the async nature of the setState it's not working properly?

Here's my function

```
async create(e){
        e.preventDefault()
        var type = this.type.value
        var obj  = {'id':this.NextId(type),'description':this.description.value,'amount':this.amount.value}
        if (type ==="expense"){
            obj.percentage   = "%100"

            var newState = this.state.setState((prevState)=>({
                expense:[...prevState.expense,obj],
                totalExpense:prevState.budget - parseInt(this.amount.value)
            }))
        }
        else{
            var newState = this.state.setState((prevState)=>({
                income:[...prevState.income,obj],
                totalIncome:prevState.totalIncome + parseInt(this.amount.value)

            }))
        }


        this.state.setState({budget:this.state.totalIncome  - this.state.totalExpense,percentage:this.getPercentage()}))        
    }
```

Comment: setState does not return anything, so `var newState = this.state.setState(...` doesn't make sense. If you need to use the most up to date value for `totalIncome`, either save it as a local variable in this function, or use the callback `setState(prev => ...` and get `totalIncome` from `prev`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a new function which treated the setState as a Promise

```
async PromiseSate(state){
       await new Promise(resolve => this.setState(state,resolve))
    }
var exampleSetState = PromiseState({data:"data"})
```

Then you could do like this

```
exampleSetState.then("your code goes here")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `setState` callback in your case,

For example lets say you want to update budget after the expense is updated you can pass a function as callback for `setState`

```
this.setState(prevState => ({ expense: prevState.expense -10   }), () => {
  this.setState(prevState => ({ budget: prevState.totalIncome - prevState.expense }))
})
```

Or you can update multiple items at the same time

```
this.setState(prevState => ({ expense: prevState.expense -10, budget: prevState.budget - 10 }))
```

Comment: Thanks but i know this kind of thing existed,this is one of the same thing.I just fixed the problem by consuming a setState funciton like a promise by using async|await and after it was consumed i then did the thing.

Comment: If you could i was having three setState functions,the first was executed if the item is an expense and the second one was used if item was an income.The third one should executed after one of the previous states gets changed so writing this explicitly in both setState functions doesn't make any sense when that's the actual thing i wanted to solve!